# Negation of a statement with an implication

Tags: logic

Could anyone help me with the negation of this statement?

$(p ∨ q) ∧ (¬ p → r)$

I know when you negate $(p ∨ q)$ it will become $(¬p ∧ ¬q)$, but I am confused about the negation of the rest of the statement. I don't know how to negate an implication.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to translate an implication into a disjunction?  Then your problem is solved.  Alternately, an implication is only true when the antecedent is true and the consequent is false.

Answer (score 3):

The negation of a statement of the form $a \wedge b$ is of the form
$$\neg (a \wedge b) \equiv \neg a\lor \neg b$$
by DeMorgan's law. As you note,
$$\neg (p \lor q) \equiv \neg p \wedge \neg q.$$
An implication is false if and only if its antecedent is true and its consequent false. That is,
$$\neg (a \implies b) \equiv a \wedge \neg b.$$
Therefore,
$$\neg (\neg p \implies r) = \neg \neg p \wedge \neg r \equiv p \wedge \neg r.$$
Putting this all together:
$$\neg[(p \lor q) \wedge (\neg p\implies r)] = (\neg p \wedge \neg q) \lor (p \wedge \neg r).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a \to b \equiv \neg a \vee b$

Answer (score 1):

$A\to B$ is valued as false exactly when we value $A$ as true and $B$ as false.